# query base object based on a non related entity list using entity framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I have the following model:

A workflowconfiguration has a Brand and also has a type.
A Workflowconfiguration has a collection of Approvers.
The Approvers entity has property Status and username.

In another part of the application, we have an entity called RequestBase
This entity has a string property called CurrentStatus.

I need to make a query with linq or EF Lambda expressions that returns me ALL requests which status matches the username on the approvers entity.
I know its a little bit complicated, or really much complicated, lol.

These are my entities(simplified)

```
public class RequestBase
    {
        public int RequestBaseId { get; set; }
        public string CurrentStatus { get; set; }
      }


 public class WorkflowConfiguration
    {
        public int WorkflowConfigurationId { get; set; }
        public WorkflowType WorkflowType { get; set; }
        public Brand Brand { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Approver> Approvers { get; set; }

    }


public class Approver
    {
        public Approver()
        {

        }

        public Approver(string approverUserName)
        {
            Name = approverUserName;
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string StepName { get; set; }  -----||||>>>>>> Must match status?
        public int Order { get; set; }
    }
```

and my query?
obviously it does not even compile

```
return _context.RequestBases.
                        .Where(a => a.CurrentStatus.Any(workflowconfiguration.Select(b=>b.Approvers.Select(c => c.StepName))));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_context.RequestBases
.Where(rb => _context.Workflowconfiguration
    .Any(wc => wc.Approvers
        .Any(a => a.StepName == rb.CurrentStatus)));
```